# Non ascii characters in Python again

Tags: python

How can I successfully add non-ASCII character into Python source code?

For example:

a = "ű"    - Hungarian letter

```
--------Sample------
#-*- coding: iso8859_2 -*-
a = "ű"
print "ű"
---------------------
output = √
```

Not ű, as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using Python on a US Windows console. I say this because the character you actually received is the cp437-encoded character for the iso8859_2 character you printed.  Unfortunately, cp437 doesn't support `ű`.  If you want to see that character you can't use the US Windows console.  Use Idle or Pythonwin.

You should also use Unicode strings.  When you use `coding: iso8859_2` you are declaring "the characters in this source file were encoded to disk using the [ISO 8859-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) translation table."  If you follow that link you'll find the the value 251 represents `ű`.  If you write that same byte value to a [cp437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) terminal, you'll get a square root symbol.  With a Unicode string, Python will translate the byte 251 into the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf) character U+0171, which uniquely identifies the character LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE ACUTE.  When printing to a terminal, Python will translate a Unicode character into the terminal encoding if possible, or throw an error instead of writing garbage for an unsupported character.

#### Example

```
# coding: iso8859_2
import unicodedata as ud
s = 'ű'
u = u'ű'
print 'ISO 8859-2 value:',ord(s)
print 'Unicode value:   ',ord(u)
print 'Unicode name:    ',ud.name(u)
print 'Unicode name of cp437 value %d: %s' % (ord(s),ud.name(s.decode('cp437')))

print s
print u
```

#### Output

```
ISO 8859-2 value: 251
Unicode value:    U+0171
Unicode name:     LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE ACUTE
Unicode name of cp437 value 251: SQUARE ROOT
√
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ex.py", line 11, in <module>
    print u
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0171' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

So you see the byte string printed the incorrect square root symbol (√) while the Unicode string correctly showed the character is not supported.

Comment: Awesome stuff Mark - truly astonishing, much appreciate Your time and shared knowledge. That's exactly what I have been facing for the last days. Reading huge bunch of documentation related to this topic made me only bigger dump, simply because nothing worked. You blow this "clouds" away - thanks a lot. You are awesome "stackoverflow". Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 3):

The other answers mention specifying the coding and making sure the source file is encoded with it, which are both correct. In addition, using unadorned quotes as you are only works in Python 3. If you're using Python 2, insert a `u` in front to make it a Unicode string:

```
a = u"ű"
print u"ű"
```

Edit: It's also possible that your console simply isn't displaying the Unicode characters properly; I've run into that. Since your editor appears to display them ok, try redirecting the output to a file and open it with your editor.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use utf-8 instead of iso8859-2 like :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = "ű"
print "ű"
```

Ouput:

```
ű
```

In addition, be sure that you have saved your source code file with the right encoding (utf-8 here).

Comment: Thanks for speed light answer. I believe this is something with my Python version (2.4). I tried that before

Comment: Thanks for speed light answer. I believe this might be a problem with my Python v 2.4 (work station). Apparently I tried that already and this gives me "┼▒" Appreciate all You coments guys!!!

Comment: Are you sure that your source code file has the right encoding ?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the enconding to utf-8 works.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = "ű"
print "ű"
```

Comment: Thanks for speed light answer. Apparently this has been given me this